# SQL: simple custom column in select doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, laravel

If I add custom column in select, I get this error:

> 20018 Invalid column name '2'.

Here is query example

```
SELECT
    [msg].[MessageTo],
    [msg].[MessageFrom],
    [msg].[SendTime],
    [msg].[ReceiveTime],
    [msg].[id],
    '2' AS source,
    [kat].[id] AS [CategoriId],
    [kat].[naziv] AS [CategoriName]
FROM
    [SMSServer_1].[dbo].[MessageIn] AS [msg]
LEFT JOIN [Tekijanka].[dbo].[crm_poruka] AS [por] ON [por].[fk_poruka] = [msg].[id]
AND [por].[fk_source] = [2]
LEFT JOIN [Tekijanka].[dbo].[crm_kategorije_poruka] AS [kat] ON [kat].[id] = [por].[fk_kategorija]
WHERE
    msg.id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            fk_poruka
        FROM
            Tekijanka.dbo.crm_poruka
        WHERE
            fk_status <> 1
    )
ORDER BY
    [SendTime] DESC
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: `AND [por].[fk_source] = [2]`? There is no column name  `[2]` in any table. Probably you want `AND [por].[fk_source] = 2` 2 is a integer value, [2] is identifier

Comment: and por,fk_source = 2 .
"por" is table "crm_poruka"....I need it in join condition

Comment: Remove square brackets. There is no column named `[2]`.

Comment: I use laravel eloquent and it automatically adds square brackets, I force it to dont add, and now it works....Thanks a lot, you helped me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `LEFT JOIN`, not in the `SELECT` section:

```
AND [por].[fk_source] = [2]
```

This condition tries to join `fk_source` and column **named** `[2]`. Of course, there's no such column in tables `MessageIn` and `crm_poruka`. You have to change this part of the code (remove the condition or change it to `AND [por].[fk_source] = 2`).